# Property Bag values in task summary search

Tags: search-results, task-list

I've created a task summary overall project sites with a `search results webpart`. We've also stored some properties in the `propertybag` of the sites like project number, project area, ...

Is it possible to get these values also in the display template of the task summary and also in the refiners?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them as index properties, [SPWeb.IndexedPropertyKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.indexedpropertykeys.aspx)

```
web.AllProperties["prop1"] = "value1";
web.IndexedPropertyKeys.Add("prop1");
web.Update();
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. we've already stored the property bag values like you wrote. the main question is that i want to use the property bag value e.g. a project number for a task allocation which was created with a search results web part. so i have to add the property bag value at my display template but how?